# How do I use setuid in Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, setuid

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928190/python-run-command-as-normal-user-in-a-root-script) but I couldn't solve my problem. I don't know how do I use setuid

I have a small python app that runs python commands and bash command in linux machine. I want only this part below to run as normal user. App run with `sudo python3 app.py` because do some commands that need sudo privilege. I upload only the part I want to run as normal user.

How can I do that?

```
import alsaaudio

m = alsaaudio.Mixer('Capture')
m.setvolume(10) # set volume
vol = m.getvolume() # get volume float value
```

Comment: if you run via `sudo` then you already have superuser privileges. what is the problem then?

Comment: Sounds like OP want's to drop privileged for part of the execution?

Comment: @Sören I want this three lines to run as normal user. As I said python has many lines that require root privilege.  Those three  lines I want to run as normal user without sudo.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I said those three lines I want to run as normal user.

Answer (score 2):

One can't simply change the owner of a process back and forth at will (ok, one can with the proper call: `os.seteuid`, I learned after starting this answer. Either way, there are more things required for this particular question than just setting the UID - the bottom part of the answer has a subprocess approach): just the root user can do that, and once its done, it is no longer root to switch back. So the trick is to call it in a process that is exclusive to run the limited tasks.

You can fork the process and call `os.setuid` on the child, and then terminate it:

```
import alsaaudio
import os
import sys
...

if not os.fork():
    # this block just runs on the child process: fork returns a non-0 PID on the parent
    os.setuid(<usernumber>)
    m = alsaaudio.Mixer('Capture')
    m.setvolume(10) # set volume
    vol = m.getvolume() # get volume float value
    sys.exit(0)  # terminates the child process. 

# normal code that will just run on the parent process (as root)
# continues:
...
```

Of course, this won't make the `vol` variable avaliable on the parent process - you have to setup a way to pass the value along.

In that case, one can use Python multiprocessing, instead of fork, with multiprocessing.Queue to send `vol` value, and add the needed pauses to destroy the other user process: that is good if you are writing "production quality" code that will need to handle a lot of corner cases in third party computers. If your object is a simple script for setting up stuff in your box, writting the value to a file, and reading it on parent will be easier:

```
import alsaaudio
import os
import sys
import tempfile
import time
import pickle


...

_, file_ = tempfile.mkstemp()

if not os.fork():
    # this block just runs on the child process: fork returns a non-0 PID on the parent
    os.setuid(<usernumber>)
    m = alsaaudio.Mixer('Capture')
    m.setvolume(10) # set volume
    vol = m.getvolume() # get volume float value
    with open(file_, "wb") as file:
         pickle.dump(vol, file)
    sys.exit(0)  # terminates the child process. 

# normal code that will just run on the parent process (as root)
# continues:

time.sleep(0.1)  # may need calibration
vol = pickle.load(open(file_, "rb"))
os.unlink(file_)
...
```

Given the OP comments, this is not just a matter of changing the effective UID, but also environment variables, and reimporting the `alsaaudio` module - a "fork" won't cut it (as env vars are not changed, and changing `os.environment` entries on the Pythonside will probably not be reflected on the native-code side of alsalib as it is initialized.

In this case, running the process with `subprocess.Popen` and ensuring the correct enviroment prior to it can attain the desired effects. Interprocess comunication can be resolved by capturing the subprocess stdout - so we can refrain from both the pickle.Also, the default subprocess call is synchronous, and no need for an arbitrary pause for the target child to initialize alsa and pick its value: the main process will continue just after the child is done, in the default call.

I am not trying alsaaudio here, it may be that more environment variables than the 2 I set are needed on the subprocess. If that is the case, just go on adding then to the `env={ ...}`   part of the code as needed.

This sample just do what you asked, and pass the value for "vol" back - if you ever need more data, drop the "encoding" argument to the subprocess, and pickle arbitrary data to `sys.stdout` on the child process - you can then retriev it with pickle.loads on `proc.stdout`

```
import alsaaudio
import os
import sys

import tempfile
import time
import pickle

vol = None

def child_code():
    import alsaaudio 
    # no need to reload: when running as a subprocess, the top-level import (if any)
    # will also run as the new user
    m = alsaaudio.Mixer('Capture')
    m.setvolume(10) # set volume
    vol = m.getvolume() # get volume float value
    print(vol)
    
    ...


def parent_code():

    import subprocess
    import pwd
    target_user = 1000
    user_data = os.getpwuid(target_user).pw_dir()
    # if alsalib fails, you may need to setup other variables
    env = {"HOME": user_data, "PWD": user_data, }
    # __file__ bellow may have to be changed if this code
    # is in a submodule in a larger project.
    proc = subprocess.run(
        ["/usr/bin/env", "python3", __file__  ], 
        env=env,
        user=target_user,
        capture_output=True,
        encoding="utf-8"
    )
    vol = literal_eval(proc.stdout)
    return vol
    ...
    
if os.getuid() == 0:
    # runs  on parent, UID==1, process
    vol = parent_code()
else:
    # runs on subprocess.
    child_code()
    sys.exit(0)

...
```

Comment: I replace `os.setuid(<usernumber>)` with 1000 but It doesn't work. It tha same. It run as root user.

Comment: These lines are run as user 1000 - but it maybe that alsaaudio performs some initiaization when imported - under the root user. 

Try adding `from importlib import reload; reload(alsaudio)` inside the guarded block, after calling `os.setuid`.

Comment: It may still not work  - but it is the same idea: `reload(alsaaudio)` will just reload the parent module in the project - if the initialization is performed in an internal submodule of the alsaudio, it is that specific submodule that must be reloaded.

Comment: It says `Failed to create secure directory (/root/.config/pulse): Permission denied`

Comment: so - now you know what is going on: it indeed initialize stuff on loading - but just changing the UID of the process does not help: the enrionment variables have to be changed as wll, so that it goes to teh config dir of the target user. At this point, probably using the full `subprocess.Popen` call, setting the apropriate enviroment will be better than "fork".

Comment: There, I added a 3rd snippet that might work as is.

Comment: I am sorry It doesn't work error message `alsaaudio.ALSAAudioError: Unable to find mixer control Capture,0 [default]`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the contents of this question.

You might try a mini-program that will just do that and run as a regular user. If that works, check the ENV variables, and proceed to setting then in the proper place - either one by one untill it work.

Or just try copying all environ to the subprocess and just override the home dir and pwd - change the line that creates env to: `env = os.environ.copy(); env.update({"HOME": user_data, "PWD": user_data, })`

Comment: @jsbuueno the problem is that line ` m = alsaaudio.Mixer('Capture')` This line is main reason that I asked here. Please help me I don't know how do I solve this problem.

Comment: Create a mimimum standalone program running as  non-root that does just that. If that works, what you need to do is set the correct variables in the code I wrote here. Id it does not work, ask a second question to get that working. 
I have no more to say on what is put here, and I am starting to repeat stuff.

Comment: The programm run without sudo. When I run witho sudo it fails. I change your code with only one line ls -al and then it doesn't work. I don't know what line I have to change.

Comment: I think `parent_code` it doesn't run at all. Please would you like to help me? I try a lot of hours to solve this problem with your code but I can't

Comment: Sorry- UID for root is "0" not "1" - just update the "if" the select callign parent_code to 0. ( i will fix it here)

Comment: I changed to 0. Now the new error is `user_data = os.getpwuid(target_user).pw_dir()
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'getpwuid'`